# ThreeJS GLTF Exporter and Face Materialindex

Tags: three.js, face, gltf

The materialindex for every face of a model exported from Blender using the GLTF exporter is returning 0 for me.  Is that correct?  The model is using 6 different materials.

[image]

Comment: Your model probably has six meshes with different materials for each now. I would not expect specific materials on specific faces — as Blender stores them — to remain represented that way in realtime engines.

Comment: I added a pic to the post to show exactly how the model is structured.

Comment: Ok yeah, I expect that will become 6 meshes (one for each material) in three.js.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  Is there a way to not have it as 6 different materials but only one mesh in ThreeJS using the GLTF exporter?

Comment: You could merge them after export using [`BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries) and the "useGroups" option. But note that with six materials, there's no performance benefit to merging them – it's six draw calls either way. Best to use vertex colors and a single material if you want a single mesh exported.

Comment: The reason I'd like to access the materialindex is for when a raycaster ray hits a face, it'd be more efficient for me to know the material of that face.

Comment: You'll know this way because it will return a different mesh, with a different material. ;) But regardless, Blender's representation does not export through to three.js.